# How SearchView of my Action Bar can works on a ListView?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-actionbar, searchview

I'm having difficulties to making the SearchView of my Action Bar works in this code. Really do not know much what to do because I am new to developing for Android, java and everything else. So ... would like to help someone to be able to do at least one search engine of Android  search the words of my ListView in a database of my app.

Thanks!

```
package br.com.jandeilson.myproject;

import br.com.jandeilson.myproject.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

public class ListarActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.listar_activity_actions, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
               (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_new:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Inserir.class));
        return true;
        default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listar);
    }

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("objetos.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        // Tabela de objetos
        StringBuilder sqlClientes = new StringBuilder();
        sqlClientes.append("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS objetos (");
        sqlClientes.append("_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ");
        sqlClientes.append("nomeobj VARCHAR(30)); ");
        db.execSQL(sqlClientes.toString());

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM objetos", null);

        String[] from = {"nomeobj"};
        int[] to = {R.id.NomeObj};

        android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter ad = new android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                R.layout.listar_model, cursor, from, to);

        ListView ltwDados = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ltwDados);

        ltwDados.setAdapter(ad);


        ltwDados.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapter, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                SQLiteCursor c = (SQLiteCursor) adapter.getAdapter().getItem(position);

                Intent it = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Editar.class);
                it.putExtra("id", c.getInt(0));
                startActivity(it);
            }
        });

        db.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link - [Search Overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html)

Sample in your sdk folder: `sdk/samples/android-15/SearchableDictionary/`

**upd**: 
something like this:

```
private void loadWords() throws IOException {
            Log.d(TAG, "Loading words...");

            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("one");
            list.add("two");


            for ( String str: list){
                addWord( str, ""); // word, def.
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "DONE loading words.");
        }
```

upd:

```
public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {


    //was the text just cleared?
    boolean justCleared = false;


    public Drawable imgClearIcon = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init();
    }

    /* Required methods, not used in this implementation */
    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }
    /* Required methods, not used in this implementation */
    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }


    void init()
    {
        // Set the bounds of the button
        this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, imgClearIcon, null);

        // button should be hidden on first draw
        clrButtonHandler();

        //if the clear button is pressed, clear it. Otherwise do nothing
        this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {

                CustomAutoCompleteTextView et = CustomAutoCompleteTextView.this;

                if (et.getCompoundDrawables()[2] == null)
                    return false;

                if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                    return false;

                if (event.getX() > et.getWidth() - et.getPaddingRight() - imgClearIcon.getIntrinsicWidth())
                {
                    et.setText("");
                    CustomAutoCompleteTextView.this.clrButtonHandler();
                    justCleared = true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    void clrButtonHandler()
    {

        if (this == null || this.getText().toString().equals("") || this.getText().toString().length() == 0)
        {
            //Log.d("CLRBUTTON", "=cleared");
            //remove clear button
            this.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);
        }
        else
        {
            //Log.d("CLRBUTTON", "=not_clear");
            //add clear button
            this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, imgClearIcon, null);
        }
    }
}
```

....

```
public class AutoCompleteTextAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
    ArrayList<String> mSuggestions = null;
    ....
    @Override
public Filter getFilter(){
    Filter myFilter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if ( charSequence != null ){


                // Now assign the values and count to the FilterResults object
                if ( mSuggestions != null ){
                    filterResults.values = mSuggestions.toArray();
                    filterResults.count = mSuggestions.size();
                }

                Log.e(TAG, "performFiltering: finish;");

            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            Log.d(TAG, "publishResults: " + charSequence);
            if ( filterResults != null && filterResults.count > 0 )
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            else
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();




        }
    };
    return myFilter;
}

public void updateList ( ArrayList<String> str ){


    mSuggestions = str;


    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

add this in your custom action bar layout:

```
    <br.com.jandeilson.forgob.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_actionbar_AutoComplete"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:ems="7"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
    android:hint="hint here"

    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"

    android:textColor="#FFFFFF">

    </br.com.jandeilson.forgob.CustomAutoCompleteTextView>
```

write this into on resume:

```
ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList<String>( ) ;

        //List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(",")));

        list.addAll(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(cursor.getColumnNames()))); // not getColumnNames() need use here;
        adapter.updateList(  list );
```

Comment: Had seen this example, but do not know how to apply it to my example.

Comment: this sample using DB too, but loading data from txt file.
see class: `DictionaryDatabase`
and method `private void loadWords()`

line: `InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.definitions);`

Just replace this to your List;

Comment: I did as you said, but unfortunately could not apply this example in my code. You could help me if I provide my source code?

Comment: Thank you! :) Here is my project: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=34A2904BAA33CF84!1565

Comment: yeap, I saw. I don't know how to use google sample for dynamic data, but...
You can use AutoCompleteTextView, need to create CustomAutoCompleteTextView and create AutoCompleteTextAdapter. And create custom action bar;

Comment: upd: sorry, have no time to write full example :(

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm trying to add the AutoCompleteTextView but without success yet. :(

Comment: in `ListarActivity` add this for start ( in onCreate method ):
`getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);
 getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);`

and this `customAutoCompleteTextView = (CustomAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_actionbar_AutoComplete);`

Comment: you just need to call 
adapter.update ( list )...; in onResume() and put list of suggestions from DB; 

note: i never used sql lite DB, so i don't know how to get list from there. I used ORM lite;

Comment: did everything as you instructed, the application starts normally but for some reason does not happen any action when I type a word.

Comment: you need just to add suggestions to adapter;
and also need check: how works filter in the adapter; 

note: for searching you need to type at least two letters;

Comment: When I add the `adapter.updateList(  list );`, he introduces error adapter can not be resolved

Comment: Another thing... `public class AutoCompleteTextAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable` display error "Implicit super constructor ArrayAdapter<String>() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor"

Comment: You doing something wrong. 
It's working but showing all suggestions. 
I try to 'send' you 'my' project;

Comment: I'm probably missing somewhere, unfortunately. : (

Thank you for your help! Will be of great help to send me the project so I can check more attention to where I'm going wrong.

Comment: How can I send you this proj ? 
'file share' site, e-mail, skype ?

Comment: for e-mail... my email is jandeilson@live.com thanks!

Comment: I got the code! Now it worked! Thank you! Although it is suggested all suggestions.

Comment: yeah, I know. Need to write 'something' in the `publishResults` method

Comment: I still do not know what to do ... but thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Ok, I will try to do something with that, and write here;

Comment: I tried some codes based on some research I did here and on Google but without success. Has this tutorial here: http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.com.br/2013/08/android-listview-with-searchview.html I thought it interesting, but I could not make it work for me.

Comment: you tested something in my code? Any results? I still can not make it work the suggestions as it should. Thanks!

Comment: Just write something into performFiltering. 
In param. you get a char set, that user wrote, and search this char set in mSuggestions and delete all from mSuggestions thats not contains 'writed', by user, symbols. 
mSuggestions - it's a list that will be show to user as suggestion.